# Is there a Mac key combination to open a link in the same tab?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

While in Chrome on Mac, I can click a link while holding CMD to force the link to open in a tab behind the one I'm reading. Is there a similar key that could force a link that would normally open in a new tab to open in my current tab?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the web page. If it’s set to open in a new tab you can’t override it. If not, just click.